# Узгодження прикметників з пошанною множиною

Tags: вибір-слова, узгодження-слів, пошанна-множина

Кожна жінка хотіла б почути таку фразу: "Ви сьогодні *прекрасна*". В даному реченні прикметник узгоджується зі словом *Ви* в однині. Але наприклад у реченні: "Ви були *відсутні* на діловій вечері?" прикметник узгоджується в множині. То ж як правильно узгоджувати прикметники з пошанною множиною (*Ви*)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У діловому мовлені пошанну множину ***Ви*** бажано узгоджувати з прикметником у множині.

> *Ви зорієнтовані в цьому питанні.*

У невимушеному спілкуванні – в однині.

> *Світлано, ви неперевершена!*

Більш детально можна ознайомитися у **["Експрес-урок української"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q7KI_6x_w8g&index=40&list=PLpjP6nb03Z4k5Wdj8qOj3s_o49a0f9qxX)** з Олександром Авраменко.